# Can I have a main() Click function that invokes all other sub-commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I have a script like:

```
#myscript.py
import click

def step1(arg1):
    print('Step 1: ' + arg1)

def step2(arg2):
    print('Step 2: ' + arg2)

def main(arg1, arg2):
    step1(arg1)
    step2(arg2)
```

*Most of the time* I want to run the script with `myscript arg1 arg2`, but occasionally I might want to run only one step: e.g. `myscript step1 arg1`. **How do I set up click to do this?** Is there a way to have one default command and then other optional ones?

This seems to be the *one thing* that [Click discourages](http://click.pocoo.org/6/advanced/#invoking-other-commands):

> Sometimes, it might be interesting to invoke one command from another command. This is a pattern that is generally discouraged with Click, but possible nonetheless.

**Do I need to use this `click.invoke()` pattern?**

Comment: I believe the author is discouraging you from having one command invoke another using `subprocess.call` or similar. Using a command line flag would work fine. Additionally, adding strings, especially inside of a print statement is generally considered poor style. For your case you could just have `print('Step1:', arg1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't phrase the question to fully explain what I was trying to do, since each step also requires the output from the previous one. Huge thanks to [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376414/4047679) for starting me on the right path.

My solution was something like:

```
@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@click.option('--arg1')
@click.option('--arg2')
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    '''Description
    '''
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        do_everything(ctx, arg1, arg2)

@cli.command()
@click.option('--arg1')
def step_1(arg1):
    return do_something(arg1)

@cli.command()
@click.argument('step_one_result')
@click.option('--arg2')
def step_2(step_one_result, arg2):
    do_something_else(step_one_result, arg2)

def do_everything(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    step_one_result = ctx.invoke(step_1, arg1=arg1)
    ctx.invoke(do_something_else, step_one_result=step_one_result, arg2=arg2)

#and because of weirdness with pass_context and using setuptools

def main():
    cli(obj={})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT:** you'll notice the use of [`ctx.invoke()`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.Context.invoke) which was necessary to call the functions without getting the following error

```
line 619, in make_context
    ctx = Context(self, info_name=info_name, parent=parent, **extra)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg1'
```

Comment: Lol I just realized my answer edit answers uses my **second bolded question**

Answer (score 5):

I think the [Multi Command Chaining](http://click.pocoo.org/6/commands/#multi-command-chaining) and [Multi Command Pipelines](http://click.pocoo.org/6/commands/#multi-command-pipelines) features are designed to cover this situation. Pipelining gives the exact behaviour requested (both `step1` and `step2` invoked when nothing is given on the command line), but it's more verbose, and with `chain=True` none of the arguments can be optional; you must either (a) always give both `arg1` and `arg2`, even when invoking only `step2`; or (b) convert these arguments to options (`--arg1 foo` instead of `foo`).

### Chaining

```py
import click

@click.group(chain=True)
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.argument('arg1')
def step1(arg1):
    click.echo('Step 1: ' + arg1)

@cli.command()
@click.argument('arg2')
def step2(arg2):
    click.echo('Step 2: ' + arg2)

cli()
```

Then:

```
$ python3 chain.py step1 foo step2 bar
Step 1: foo
Step 2: bar
$ python3 chain.py step2 bar
Step 2: bar
```

### Pipelining

```
import click

@click.group(chain=True, invoke_without_command=True)
@click.argument('arg1')
@click.argument('arg2')
def cli(arg1, arg2):
    pass

@cli.resultcallback()
def process_pipeline(processors, **kwargs):
    # If no commands given, invoke step1 then step2
    processors = processors if len(processors) else [step1, step2]
    for processor in processors:
        processor(**kwargs)

def step1(**kwargs):
    click.echo('Step 1: ' + kwargs['arg1'])

def step2(**kwargs):
    click.echo('Step 2: ' + kwargs['arg2'])

@cli.command('step1')
def make_step1():
    return step1

@cli.command('step2')
def make_step2():
    return step2

cli()
```

Then

```
$ python3 pipeline.py foo bar
Step 1: foo
Step 2: bar
$ python3 pipeline.py foo bar step2
Step 2: bar
```

Comment: `invoke_without_command=True` started me on the right path. Sorry I should've written the question better. Will investigate the `chain=True` element to chain steps.